# Selenium WebDriver: Not able to run the tests in chrome browser on centos 6, getting unreachable browser exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the testcase on `centos 6` in `chrome browser`.

my **chrome browser version is 51** and **chrome driver is 2.9**.

Please help me out. i am running into problems.

I have attached image file which describes the error [`Unreachable browser excpetion`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlCIl.png)

Comment: From the attached screenshot it is understood that there are some dependencies missing for the chromedriver to launch. Can you please try after keeping all those lib files

Comment: Sure karthik, i will install the necessary dependenies, give a try and get back to you. thanks.